# ASP.NET MVC Cache SQL results to XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

When working with ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server we are wondering if caching to XML is still something to think about or are their other possibilities for this?

Like for instance we have a table called `Customers`. If you call this db table everytime you click on Customers or do sorting or filtering in the app why not store this info in a xml file.

Then you work only with the xml file and not the db and you update the xml after adding changes to the customers table.

Comment: Accessing from a database is faster than xml and database you can have multiple users making changes while xml is only single user.  If you have xml in memory then you can change one element at a time from database.  But limit the number of times you read and write to file which take time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an absolutely brilliant idea.

If:

- You only have 1 client
- Or you have multiple client but they don't mind seeing old data
- You have a database system that doesn't provide caching possibilities
- You do not use database access frameworks that can handle caching for you

In short, no, it actually is almost never a good idea.

Databases are *made* to be used. Most of them can handle a much higher load than programmers think they can, as long as you treat them well. If necessary, a lot of them provide perfectly fine caching possibilities to improve performance *if needed*.

Any useful type of caching in your application should involving refreshing that cache when anything changes. Implementing that by yourself is usually not a good idea. If you *do* want a very simple cache of data that was just on the screen before the user clicked away, *memory* would be the place for it, not a file system. Unless you need centralised session cache, but that goes way beyond "let's write some xml".

Answer (score 0):

Caching to xml file is bad choice. Database system can handle load of 100 users in 5 seconds if you have 50000 records in your table. If you want more speed than this then try using In-memory sql which stores data in RAM for fast access. But for it you need high RAM capacity on server.